# h2o package not initiating in R; required ports are not available

Tags: r, h2o

I am running RStudio 1.0.136 on a server through my browser. I installed the package and can call the library. But when I type h2o.init(), it takes a while and then it gives me the following error:

```
h2o.init()
```

H2O is not running yet, starting it now...

Note:  In case of errors look at the following log files:
    /tmp/RtmplsTxlS/h2o_aelard_started_from_r.out
    /tmp/RtmplsTxlS/h2o_aelard_started_from_r.err

openjdk version "1.8.0_141"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_141-b16)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.141-b16, mixed mode)

Starting H2O JVM and connecting: localhost/127.0.0.1 some of the required ports 54321, 54322 are not available, change -port PORT and try again. 
 "localhost"
 54321
 FALSE
 502

Error in h2o.init() : H2O failed to start, stopping execution.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is mentioned in the last line

```
localhost/127.0.0.1 some of the required ports 54321, 54322 are not available, 
change -port PORT and try again. "localhost" 54321 FALSE 502
```

It says, "some of the required ports 54321, 54322 are not available". Check and make sure those ports are available

If you can't free them for any reason, you can always start  on a different port using the port argument in h2o.init().

see [here](https://rdrr.io/cran/h2o/man/h2o.init.html)

Comment: I have the exact same problem and can't resolve it . Even if i specified a new port